# sql left join - return a default value if no results

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, default

Does anyone know how return a default value if a left join has no values returned?

Here is my code

```
 SELECT 
     colName
 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2
 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
 WHERE table1.ID = value
```

I want to return "There are no results found"

**Example**

```
SELECT 
ISNULL(photoName, 'No Photos Found') as (photoName, 
FROM usertable
LEFT OUTER JOIN
phototable
ON
usertable.id= phototable.id
WHERE userID = 1
```

User Table

```
Id | User
0  | Jack
```

Photo Table

```
ID | Photo
0  | me.jpg
```

Comment: the rdsbms is sql server

Comment: so use `isnull` :  `SELECT 
     isnull(colName,'defalut value')
 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2
 ON table1.ID = table2.ID `

Comment: but when i add  a where clause it doesnt work

Comment: You don't really need a join here. You already have the ID of the table2 side. `SELECT coalesce(colname, 'no results') FROM table2 WHERE ID = value`

Comment: I need to join the tables

Comment: Relocate your `where` clause on second table into join condition.

Comment: You should always in every query alias your table and then use the alias in every single field name. I can't tell what table these fields are from and neither will someone trying to maintain the query in six months.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few choices and syntax varies based on your platform.  Collesce, isnull, and ifnull should all work

```
SELECT 
   isnull(colName,'There are no results found')
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.ID = table2.ID
```

Comment: Thank you that works but i made a mistake cause there is a where clause.

Comment: @LeslieJones You are going from table1 left join to table2...so a where clause on table1 should function fine.  Could you give more details on 'it doesnt work'?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle:

```
nvl(colname,'There are no results found.')
```

SQL Server:

```
isnull(colname,'There are no results found.')
```

MySQL:

```
ifnull(colname,'There are no results found.')
```

Just about any database:

```
coalesce(colname,'There are no results found.')
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is likely the where clause. If it is on a column that is in phototable, then you have turned the left join into an inner join. Put that condition as part of the where clause instead.

Or the problem could be the join, It does not seem likely to me that the ID field from two different tables is the correct thing to join on. But that of course depends entirely on the meaning of the data in your database. Incidentally it is things like this which is exactly why ID without a prefix is a very poor thing to ever use because the meaning is not clear. It is a SQL Antipattern.

Or the problem might be that you want a record returned if there are no records found at all which is an entirely different problem. That requires a UNION ALL statement.

```
SELECT 
ISNULL(photoName, 'No Photos Found') as photoName 
FROM usertable
LEFT OUTER JOIN
phototable
ON
usertable.id= phototable.id
WHERE userID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT  'No Photos Found' as  photoName
where (SELECT 
Count(*)
FROM usertable
LEFT OUTER JOIN
phototable
ON
usertable.id= phototable.id
WHERE userID = 1) = 0
```